# Как из python отправить сообщение в VK

Tags: python, вконтакте

Нужно с использованием vk api отправить сообщение пользователю, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import vk_api

# Авторизуемся как сообщество
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='token_сообщества')

# Получаем доступ к API
vk = vk_session.get_api()

# Отправляем сообщение пользователю с id 123
vk.messages.send(user_id=123, message='Hello, World!')
```